# SugarCRM: Subpanel - Enable Create Button

Tags: sugarcrm, sugarbean

I am new to sugarcrm. I am working with subpanel linking Accounts & Users module with Many-To-Many relationship. After ccreating subpanel My create button in subpanel is not working.

[image]

Why was this not working? can some one guide me to make it work?

I created the Subpabel using Studio.

Comment: Is this subpanel the Accounts or Users module?  Users is a bit of a special module, only admins can create a user.  You can probably force the create action through if you need to though.  This strikes me as a bit of a strange relationship though, do you really need to link Accounts to Users?  Would a custom module do instead of Users?